# Python Tornado connections timing out early -- Any way to prevent timeout (HTTP 599 errors)?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am using Tornado to asynchronously scrape data from many thousand URLS. Each of them is 5-50MB, so they take a while to download. I keep getting "Exception: HTTP 599: Connection closed http:…" errors, *despite* the fact that I am setting both connect_timeout and request_timeout to a very large number.

Why, despite the large timeout settings, am I still timing out on some requests after only a few minutes of running the script?* Is there a way to instruct httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient to **NEVER** time out? Or is there a better solution to prevent timeouts?

The following command is how I'm calling the fetch (each worker calls this *request_and_save_url()* sub-coroutine in the *Worker()* coroutine):

```
@gen.coroutine
def request_and_save_url(url, q_all):
    try:
        response = yield httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url, partial(handle_request, q_all=q_all), connect_timeout = 60*24*3*999999999, request_timeout = 60*24*3*999999999)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception: {0} {1}'.format(e, url))
        raise gen.Return([])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note `HTTPError 599` is raised on connection or request timeout, but this is not the only case. The other one is when connection has been closed by the server before request ends (including entire response fetch) e.g. due to its (server) timeout to handle request or whatever.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, 599 is because of the size of the response. https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/test/simple_httpclient_test.py Search for 599 in this file. I got the content length too long hint from the log file.